# openssl generating valid certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, pkix

I have generated an ssl certificate using openssl using the documentation given by them. I have followed the step by step perfectly. However, the certificate is showing that it is an invalid certificate and it is showing red line cross over on https. I had done further R&D on that and i came to know that the certificate which i had generated will be good for local testing purpose at the development time, and when we go for publishing our website we should buy a certificate from a valid domain seller (ex: godaddy). My question is whether we can generate a valid ssl certificate using openssl so that we can change http to https for my already existed website. can any one please solve my query.

Comment: There are far too many factors can trigger that red cross, so you should at least dig to see what is the cause for your case, https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/tips/ST05-010

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be globally trusted, an SSL certificate must be signed by a trusted Authority. Otherwise the certificate will only provide encryption, but not trust.

Self-signed certificates are signed by yourself, hence they are not trusted as you can't guarantee for yourself. That's why they are good for local testing (or networks where you can configure the certificate to be trusted), but not when you deploy a site.

In order for you to properly configure HTTPS, you need to acquire a certificate from a Certificate Authority. You can't sign it yourself with OpenSSL.

Comment: Note the Certificate Authority and the Domain Name Registrar do not have to be the same entity.. One vendor _can_ do both and the example given, GoDaddy, does do both; but you can also get the domain name(s) from one vendor and the certificate(s?) from another, as long as you _have_ the domain(s) before you request the certificate.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 is it referred to my answer? I never mentioned that they are the same. In fact, I didn't even mention the Registrar.

Comment: Your answer didn't address DNS, but the question assumed CA=DNS ('certificate from ... domain seller').and I thought i would help to clarify. If you prefer I can move it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your self generated certificate - the one you already generated - for testing, and replace it with a commercial certificate when your web site goes live.  When you get the commercial certificate, you'll generate a key pair using openssl and use it to generate a certificate signing request to the certificate issuer, who will provide the certificate.

Comment: You generate a **Certificate Signing Request (CSR)** and send that to the CA. You should **never ever send your keypair** (aka private key) to anybody else.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Agreed, clarified answer.